# Can you keep Bethany after Act 1?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In Dragon Age 2, is there any way to keep your sister Bethany as a companion in the second and third act?

> I took her with me into the Deep Roads and she died. If you leave at home or send her to the circle, will you be able to have her on the team later?

I would really like to keep her because I used her permanently as healer and supporter. Anders can replace her quite good, but to be honest: He is annoying and whiny. ;)

Comment: *He is annoying and whiny.* ... and possessed to boot! But in all seriousness, Anders is a much better supporter/healer than Bethany. I've actually learned to not rely on either of them, but perhaps this is more relevant to the difficulty of your game setting.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing but after reading these responses I have to say that I don't think there is a way. I personally took her with me along with Isabella, Anders, and Varric (was locked in). For me however, she met the same fate as Wesley and fell to the Blight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer:

> No

Long answer:

> If you bring Anders with you, he will inform you of a Grey Warden party who can save her. You'll still lose her as a party member as she has to leave to undertake The Joining. Whether you do this or leave her at home, she will show up in the endgame and potentially fight with you. Regardless, you lose her as a party member. You'll have to get used to Anders, I'm afraid.

Regarding Carver:

> He plays out almost exactly the same (doesn't join the Circle, obviously, he has his own twist). Basically, no matter who your sibling is, you lose them as a party member. This is why they don't have specialized talents.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my research into the matter goes, you can't keep her. On top that, she's your sister so you can't romance her.

Answer (score 0):

If you play as a rogue or warrior you keep her.

Comment: This is for the prologue only and does not apply to Act 1.

Answer (score -1):

It seems this is a party balance mechanic for game start, if you're a physical damage character you lose the mage, if you are a magic damage character you lose the hitter.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot keep Bethany in your party. She will always leave. However, you can determine her fate. If you are a warrior or rogue, do not take her with you at the end of Act 1 unless you also bring Anders. If you bring Anders, she will join the Grey Wardens and will appear again later in the game (and possibly rejoin you for the climax). If you don't bring Anders, she will be taken by the Templars.